# NullPointerException в сервисе Android

Tags: android

Есть сервис, который проигрывает полученную из активити ссылку

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String radio;
    Notification notification;
    Notification status;

    public static final String KEY_STREAM = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_STREAM";
    public static final String KEY_RADIO = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_RADIO";

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setContentText("Открыть список радиостанций")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showNotificationOld() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setContentText("Открыть список радиостанций")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setDeleteIntent(pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
        this.radio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RADIO);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                showNotification();
            } else {
                showNotificationOld();
            }
            RadioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, this);

        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = false;
            RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            Player.isPlay = false;
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

А это сам класс активити

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private String img;
    private int radioID;

    DBHeler db;

    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
    static boolean isPlay = false;
    static ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtTitle;
    private RoundedImageView imgRadio;

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    private String internetStatus = "";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    private AsyncTask jsonTask;

    private ScheduledFuture<?> mScheduledFuture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        radioID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_RADIO + " WHERE " + Contract.Entry._ID + " = " + radioID;
        Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    radio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_TITLE));
                    stream = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_URL));
                    img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        setTitle(radio);
        txtRadio.setText(radio);

        try {
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("img/" + img + ".png");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            imgRadio.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }

        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
            startPlayerService();
        }

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mScheduledFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jsonTask = new ParseJSONTask().execute();
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, radio);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        mScheduledFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jsonTask = new ParseJSONTask().execute();
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
        txtTitle.setText("");
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, internetStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0 ) {
            if (isPlay) {
                stopPlayerService();
            } else {
                startPlayerService();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нет подключения к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopPlayerService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class ParseJSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("URL");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String replaceStr = "(***.ru)";

            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray radioArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("stations");

                for (int i = 0; i < radioArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject radioObject = radioArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String radioUrl = radioObject.optString("url");
                    String title = radioObject.optString("title");

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, radioUrl);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, title);

                    String radioTitle = "";
                    try {
                        radioTitle = new String(title.getBytes("Cp1252"),"Cp1251");
                        radioTitle = new String(radioTitle.getBytes(),"utf-8");
                        radioTitle = radioTitle.toLowerCase();

                        if (radioTitle.contains(replaceStr)) {
                            radioTitle = radioTitle.replace(replaceStr, "");
                        }

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (isPlay) {
                        if (radioUrl.equals(stream)) {
                            txtTitle.setText(radioTitle.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    } else {
                        txtTitle.setText("");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200 (ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1454)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5525)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at ru.test.radios.PlayerService.onStartCommand (PlayerService.java:99)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3028)
```

Ругается на строчку

```
Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Player.btnPLayPause` есть `null`.

`PlayerService.onStartCommand` вызывается до того, как был вызван `Player.onCreate`

Comment: Я понимаю что Player.btnPLayPause оказывается null, у меня никогда такой ошибки не возникает, но тем не менее в маркете показано что у 11 человек такая ошибка возникла. Как исправить?

Comment: Проблема в логике приложения. Надо гарантировать чтобы PlayerService.onStartCommand вызывался исключительно после всех инициализаций. Как это сделать конкретно в вашем случае? Недостаточно информации, я не знаю в какой момент что создается, какие ресиверы прописаны, события и прочее.

Comment: Попробую сам поковыряться.